# Golang App On Google App Engine Calling Python Scripts

Tags: python, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I would like to build an app written in Go and host it on Google App Engine. I would like it to call some Python scripts which were written for another app (and therefore not need to rewrite that code in Go).

As far as I have seen, the Google App Engine specifies the language of the app (i.e. runtime Go in that case) but it is not clear if that app could also run some Python script. Could anyone let me know if this would be possible? If not, what would be the best process? Have a separate Python service called by the Go app - ideally I would like both services to use the same domain name?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/microservices-on-app-engine/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll find good support for Python in the Go runtime, or vice versa.

Your best bet would be to define a custom runtime via [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) -- this will have all the same serverless benefits of App Engine, but will allow you to run code in both languages in the same service.